# Rest uri using Workbench

Tags: rest

How can i create a child record in Rest URI. For example how can I create a `Contact` for `Account` using Rest URI in Workbench. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If you want to execute creation of Account and Contact all in single call you can use Composite API like below

**URI**   `/services/data/v38.0/composite/`

**Request Body**

```
{
"allOrNone": true,
"compositeRequest": [{
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account",
    "referenceId": "NewAccount",
    "body": {
        "Name": "Salesforce",
        "BillingStreet": "Landmark @ 1 Market Street",
        "BillingCity": "San Francisco",
        "BillingState": "California",
        "Industry": "Technology"
    }
}, {
    "method": "GET",
    "referenceId": "NewAccountInfo",
    "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account/@{NewAccount.id}"
}, {
    "method": "POST",
    "referenceId": "NewContact",
    "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact",
    "body": {
        "lastname": "John Doe",
        "Title": "CTO of @{NewAccountInfo.Name}",
        "MailingStreet": "@{NewAccountInfo.BillingStreet}",
        "MailingCity": "@{NewAccountInfo.BillingAddress.city}",
        "MailingState": "@{NewAccountInfo.BillingState}",
        "AccountId": "@{NewAccountInfo.Id}",
        "Email": "jdoe@salesforce.com",
        "Phone": "1234567890"
    }
  }]
}
```

**Response Body**

```
{
"compositeResponse": [{
    "body": {
        "id": "001R00000033JNuIAM",
        "success": true,
        "errors": []
    },
    "httpHeaders": {
        "Location": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account/001R00000033JNuIAM"
    },
    "httpStatusCode": 201,
    "referenceId": "NewAccount"
}, {
    "body": {

    },
    "httpHeaders": {
        "ETag": "\"Jbjuzw7dbhaEG3fd90kJbx6A0ow=\"",
        "Last-Modified": "Fri, 22 Jul 2016 20:19:37 GMT"
    },
    "httpStatusCode": 200,
    "referenceId": "NewAccountInfo"
}, {
    "body": {
        "id": "003R00000025REHIA2",
        "success": true,
        "errors": []
    },
    "httpHeaders": {
        "Location": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/003R00000025REHIA2"
    },
    "httpStatusCode": 201,
    "referenceId": "NewContact"
   }]
 }
```

> If you have AccountID and want to simply use one more REST URI to create Contact use below

**URI** `/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Contact/`

**Request Body**

```
{
  "AccountId" : "001D000000IqhSLIAZ",
  "Last Name" : "Test",
  "Company" :"Test"
}
```

Comment: Does composite api allows partial dml? I mean if account insertion completes and contact's insertion fails then? Is whole transaction rollbacks or account persists?

Comment: AllOrNone specified in request decides that .